# Which Language Would be Best for Classified Ad High Traffic Website? 3000 to 20k Visitors Daily

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Average visitors: 5000.

I'm wondering should i make it in PHP or ASP.NET/C#. Website contents might grow really fast because it is expected there going to be daily/continuous posts from users. Its an interactive website that has to login, post, check replies and private messages without any advanced/complex features.

Website might use AJAX as well as JQuery.

**What language do you suggest me to go with?**

This is one time process, once project is started! That's it, no changing mind would help.

NOTE: i care to have the code be designed well so it can be extended easily in later future without having to change existing code incldung re-usability and consistency for the long run.

Comment: It's possible with both. How proficient are you (or the people who are going to build it) in each platform?

Comment: I might hire somebody for this project to avoid pitfalls that might cost me alot of money later on ... Personally, i have the basics in ASP.NET and C# which i can advanced my skills by learning intensively for few weeks or months ... I'm not easy going with PHP ...

Comment: @user then I'd say stick with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will suffice. Pick what you're familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

> i care to have the code be designed well so it can be extended easily in later future without having to change existing code incldung re-usability and consistency for the long run.

You might as well ask "What is the meaning of life?". This is a fundamental goal of every software project that have ever been and will ever be - Books have been written about this and no clear answer exists.